# Why isn't current directory on my Ruby path?

Tags: ruby, irb

Is there any reason why my present working directory is not on my Ruby path?

Consider:

```
~:499$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > puts $:
/Users/mrberryman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/Users/mrberryman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0
/Users/mrberryman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/Users/mrberryman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/Users/mrberryman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0
/Users/mrberryman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/Users/mrberryman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/Users/mrberryman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0
 => nil
```

This is really bothering me because require isn't working as I thought it would (although I'm a ruby nuby):

```
require 'some_file_that_I_know_darn_well_is_in_pwd.rb'
```

If I append `'.'` to the end, then the require works as I'd expect.

What am I missing?

---

**UPDATE:**

Arg! Now I'm getting a new problem.  Consider:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :010 > `ls`
 => "start.rb\n" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :011 > require_relative 'start'
LoadError: cannot infer basepath
    from (irb):11:in `require_relative'
    from (irb):11
    from /Users/mrberryman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Now what's up?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9.2 the Powers that Be introduced [an explicit change](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/08/18/ruby-1-9.2-released/) so that the working directory is no longer in the Ruby path. I thought it was the Apocalypse and a terrible thing, until I learned about `require_relative`. My apps tend to look like this:

```
require 'some_gem'
require 'another_gem'
require_relative 'lib/init'
```

And then `lib/init.rb` can have:

```
require_relative 'lib1' # this is lib/lib1.rb
require_relative 'lib2' # this is lib/lib2.rb
```

It's the bees knees, and solves all sorts of problems I used to have with requiring the same file from different working directories.

**Edit**: Unfortunately (for reasons I don't know and haven't looked into) `require_relative` doesn't work specifically in irb. For this you can:

1. do what you initially described: either `$: << '.'` or `$:.unshift '.'`, or
2. you can use `load 'myfile.rb'` or `require './myfile'` instead:

   ```
   irb(main):001:0> Dir['*.rb']
   => ["a.rb", "bar.rb", "foo.rb", "prime.rb", "tmp.rb"]

   irb(main):002:0> require 'a'
   LoadError: no such file to load -- a
     from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
     from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
     from (irb):2
     from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

   irb(main):003:0> require_relative 'a'
   LoadError: cannot infer basepath
     from (irb):3:in `require_relative'
     from (irb):3
     from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

   irb(main):004:0> load 'a.rb'
   a
   => true

   irb(main):005:0> require './a'
   a
   => true
   ```

Comment: You brought me closer.  Care to take a look at the updated question?

Comment: @JohnBerryman Edited to match.

Comment: Well... that's solved the problem.  Not as pretty of a solution as I had hoped for.  I wonder if this is some oversight on part of the Ruby folks.

Comment: The reason is quite simple: `require_relative` requires a file relative to the file that the `require_relative` call is in. Within IRB, the `require_relative` call isn't in any file, and thus cannot possibly work.

Comment: @Jörg That explains the engineering "why", but does not explain the user "why" of _"Hey, how about you just treat IRB as a file in the current directory, mmkay?"_

Comment: @JohnBerryman I forgot to note that `require './foo'` works in IRB and files as well. Perhaps that's a prettier solution you were looking for.

Comment: @Phrogz - I guess irb doesn't have to be pretty... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use require_relative assuming it does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the environment variable "RUBYLIB" is set with all directory paths where you will find custom *.rb code.  It drove me nuts too.

Comment: That's not necessary. See @Phrogz' answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that one.  It's a great answer (but I can't up vote it until tomorrow; out of votes).  I'm going to change some of my code to try that one out.  My way does work though.  I have code that relies on it now, but I like his way and will try that out.