# ruby LoadError: cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I require a file, for example (called st.rb):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongrel'

class TestHandler < Mongrel::HttpHandler

  def process(request, response)
    response.start(200) do |head, out|
      head["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
      out.write "Hello, World!\n"
    end
  end

end
```

in irb I get:

```
>> require 'st.rb'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- st.rb
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I might have a clue, but it's just a guess. My ruby version/install location is:

`/usr/local/bin/ruby` and `ruby 1.9.3p0`

yet, ruby gems is in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1` and it's talking about version `1.9.1`. Could this possibly be the reason?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Weird, when I type 'puts RUBY_VERSION' in IRB, I get this:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
1.9.3
NoMethodError: undefined method `write' for nil:NilClass
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `printf'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `output_value'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
Maybe IRB bug!
>>
```

Comment: what if you just `require 'st'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't current directory on my Ruby path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965556/why-isnt-current-directory-on-my-ruby-path); see my answer in that question for workarounds.

Answer (score 21):

The directory where `st.rb` lives is most likely not on your load path.

Assuming that `st.rb` is located in a directory called `lib` relative to where you invoke `irb`, you can add that `lib` directory to the list of directories that ruby uses to load classes or modules with this:

```
$: << 'lib'
```

For example, in order to call the module called 'foobar' (foobar.rb) that lives in the `lib` directory, I would need to first add the `lib` directory to the list of load path. Here, I am just appending the `lib` directory to my load path:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'foobar'
LoadError: no such file to load -- foobar
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0> $:
=> ["/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/spoon-0.0.1/lib", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/interactive_editor-0.0.10/lib", "/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8", "/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin", "/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.8", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin", "."]
irb(main):004:0> $: << 'lib'
=> ["/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/spoon-0.0.1/lib", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/interactive_editor-0.0.10/lib", "/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8", "/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin", "/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.8", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin", ".", "lib"]
irb(main):005:0> require 'foobar'
=> true
```

**EDIT**
Sorry, I completely missed the fact that you are using ruby 1.9.x. All accounts report that your [current working directory has been removed from `LOAD_PATH` for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative), so you will have to do something like in `irb`:

```
$: << "."
```

Comment: I am currently cd'ed into the directory in which st.rb resides. This was working fine until yesterday when i decided to upgrade ruby to 1.9.3

Answer (score 14):

The problem shall have solved if you specify your path. For example,

`require 'st.rb'` --> `require './st.rb'`

See if your problem get solved or not.

Comment: Thx. I came thru the problem when working on the samples of AWS.  In fact, if we tried to match the version of ruby when the sample code, the problem may disappeared.

Answer (score 11):

For security & other reasons, ruby does not by default include the current directory in the load_path. You may want to check this for more details - [Why does Ruby 1.9.2 remove "." from LOAD_PATH, and what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative)

Answer (score 2):

I created my own Gem, but I did it in a directory that is not in my load path:

```
$ pwd
/Users/myuser/projects
$ gem build my_gem/my_gem.gemspec
```

Then I ran `irb` and tried to load the Gem:

```
> require 'my_gem'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- my_gem
```

I used the global variable $: to inspect my load path and I realized I am using RVM. And rvm has specific directories in my load path `$:`. None of those directories included my ~/projects directory where I created the custom gem.

So one solution is to modify the load path itself:

```
$: << "/Users/myuser/projects/my_gem/lib"
```

Note that the lib directory is in the path, which holds the my_gem.rb file which will be required in irb:

```
> require 'my_gem'
 => true
```

Now if you want to install the gem in RVM path, then you would need to run:

```
$ gem install my_gem
```

But it will need to be in a repository like rubygems.org.

```
$ gem push my_gem-0.0.0.gem
Pushing gem to RubyGems.org...
Successfully registered gem my_gem
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across a similar problem. Try

```
require './st.rb'
```

This should do the trick.