# Errors in the Sinatra 'hello world'

Tags: ruby, linux, sinatra

Doing the [getting started](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro) of Sinatra.
I get this error:

```
./sinatra.rb:5: undefined method `get' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from sinatra.rb:3
```

Googling on these errors returns [ruby LoadError: cannot load such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154365/ruby-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file) which I don't see how that relates to `Sinatra`.

Not sure what other info I need to share to make my question clearer. So just tell me what other commands I should run to make the question clear.

**UPDATE:** Actual code

```
# sinatra.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
        'hey girl'
end
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code? External links aren't great.

Comment: Is there a place in the code where you call `get` rather than `gets` on line 5 of `sinatra.rb`?

Comment: @Linuxios Yes, there is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is due to you naming your file `sinatra.rb`. When you run that file, the first thing it does is `require 'sinatra'`, and since the current directory is on the load path in Ruby 1.8.7, it tries to load *itself*. It then gets to the call to `get '/' do ...`, but since the real Sinatra hasn’t been loaded this results in the error.

The fix is to rename your file to something other than `sinatra.rb`, you could use `myapp.rb` as suggested in page you linked to.

Comment: Thank you! Stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: Fix worked and clear explanation of how the error works internally.