# IRB require mongo fails cannot load such file -- mongo

Tags: ruby, mongodb, irb

I am following a coursera tutorial on ROR and mongo. It says go to IRB and type require 'mongo' Then try to connect to the db.

If I try

```
require 'mongo'
```

I get the following error and not sure why?

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mongo
    from /Users/balh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Comment: [ruby LoadError: cannot load such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154365/ruby-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file) - maybe? Also linked in answers there: [Why does Ruby 1.9.2 remove “.” from LOAD_PATH, and what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2900370/2313887). It's not really clear without more explanation what you have actually done, other than I do see `rbenv` in the path. Did you even install the gem? If those links don't directly answer, then you would do well to show what you have done, and what things those suggest you actually tried in attempting to resolve.

Comment: Your first link worked!!!!    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative