# The ":w ! ruby" vim command is failed to run the ruby script with "require_relative"

Tags: ruby, vim

Here is my ruby script:

```
require_relative 'lib/say.rb' 
say("hello")
```

I run it from macvim via `:w ! ruby` and got:

```
:w ! ruby
-:1:in `require_relative': cannot infer basepath (LoadError)
    from -:1:in `<main>'

shell returned 1
```

Though `! ruby %` vim command works fine.
And also changing the `require_relative...` to `require File.expand_path('../lib/say', __FILE__)` also helps...

But... What is actually wrong with these friends: `require_relative` + `:w ! ruby` ?

Why do I need this? Just to use in vim the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> shortkey from the vim-ruby-runner plugin which is based on `:w !ruby` vim command and have my code looks better with `require_relative`...

P.S.
I found the following question on SO: [Why isn't current directory on my Ruby path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965556/why-isnt-current-directory-on-my-ruby-path)
Seems the latter source correspond to my problem too... But it was hard for me to get all answers I need from there.

Comment: I love it when questions solve themselves :)

Comment: Could you please add your answer as a real answer, and accept it later?

Comment: Big thanks for pushing me! I missed that my reputation had grown and now I can unswer my own questions:) I'll accept the answer in 21h as SO told me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner of the vim-ruby-runner plugin, found the solution at http://www.rodrigoalvesvieira.com/add-require-relative-to-irb/

Plugin is fixed and can be get at https://github.com/henrik/vim-ruby-runner

Solution (and fix for vim-ruby-runner) can be also found at https://github.com/henrik/vim-ruby-runner/issues/5