# Why can't IRB locate the file to "require"?

Tags: ruby

I have a file in a directory `test/`.
The file is "test.rb".

When I start IRB and type:

```
require 'test'
require_relative 'test'
```

It returns:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- test
```

and:

```
LoadError: cannot infer basepath
```

Is my Ruby messed up?

Comment: Where do you start the IRB from?

Comment: So, when you fire up IRB, what does `Dir.getwd` say? Is it's output correct?

Comment: Do you see `test.rb` when you type `Dir.glob("*")`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `require './test'`

I think newer versions of Ruby removed the current directory from the Ruby path.

Edit:

Also, check out the answer to "[Why isn't current directory on my Ruby path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4965766/749004)" for an explanation why `require_relative` doesn't work in irb.

Comment: The explanation is in the comments on that answer, by the way.

Comment: i.e. `require` works by running this in irb first:  `$: << '.'` for me.  However, a nested `require '...'` inside the included file still relative to the original working directory, instead of the included file.

Answer (score 0):

The file which is to be required should be present in the same directory as interactive ruby is present (for windows).
For eg,
I have installed ruby in C:\ . Hence, my interactive ruby is in C:\Ruby22\bin.
So, paste the required file and type require './file' in the 'interactive ruby'.

Comment: You may want to mention why the directory containing the file matters, specifically how the path variable interacts with interactive ruby.