# How do I require a Ruby file?

Tags: ruby

I have a file called "go.rb" that contains:

```
require 'turboname'
dictionary = Turboname::Random.new

100999032982389.times do
  name = Turboname::Domain.new(:from => dictionary)
  name.save if name.length < 15 and name.available?
  tld = name.tldize
  name.save(tld) if tld and name.length < 15 and name.available?(tld)
end
```

turboname.rb is located in the same directory as go.rb.  It's the same level.  I just want to include this file in this script. I don't want to deal with gems or bundles.

```
./turboname.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- turboname/version (LoadError)
    from ./turboname.rb:1
    from go.rb:1:in `require'
    from go.rb:1
```

Comment: Do you have any trouble with your code?

Comment: Using Ruby 1.9.3 or later?

See this post and the selected answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965556/why-isnt-current-directory-on-my-ruby-path

Comment: I am using Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 3):

### Use a `require_relative` Statement

Recent Ruby versions no longer add `.` to the load path stored in `$:`. However, one solution is to use [Kernel#require_relative](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) to require a file relative to the current value of `__FILE__`. For example:

```
require_relative './turboname'
```

Note that this doesn't work in interactive REPL sessions with irb or pry, but works fine within actual source files.

Answer (score 3):

The error isn't telling you it can't find `./turboname.rb`. It's telling you that it found that file, but the first line of `./turboname.rb` tries to `require 'turboname/version'`, which Ruby can't find. Does `./turboname/version.rb` exist? If so, is it readable by the current user?

If everything else checks out, then you have a load-path problem. At the top of `go.rb`, explicitly add the current working directory (or whichever directory contains `turboname.rb` and `turboname/version.rb` (possibly `./lib/`) to your load path:

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.dirname(__FILE__) # for ./
# or
$LOAD_PATH << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib') # for ./lib/
```

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby 2.0:

```
require "#{__dir__}/turboname"
```